# azure - static outgoing ip for all VMs in a vnet

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-virtual-network

I have multiple VMs in a vnet. Vnet has a static ip attached to it's interface. The network interfaces attached to individual VMs do not have any public ip associated. My expectation is that all outgoing traffic would get routed through the vnet ip, but it isn't the case. Each VM has a different public going IP. I have tried using `curl ipinfo.io` to test.

I need to ensure that all of the internet traffic from any VM in the vnet would get routed through a static ip address.

Comment: Do you mean you didn't create  public IPs for azure VMs, and want all the VMs outgoing traffic through a static IP?

Comment: That is correct! All outgoing traffic from the vnet should go through the same IP. I want to whitelist this ip in my external services.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> All outgoing traffic from the vnet should go through the same IP. I
>   want to whitelist this ip in my external services.

If your VMs deploy in **ASM** module, all the VMs in the same cloud service use the same public IP.

If your VMs deploy in **ARM** module, and want all VMs in the Vnet outgoing traffic through the same public IP address, we can use **internet load balancer**.

Also we can deploy **S2S VPN** between them, so we can add the public IP address to whitelist.

Comment: Thanks Jason. Looks like we can use SNAT option explained here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/load-balancer/load-balancer-overview. Is it possible to use a load balancer only for outgoing traffic, and not for incoming traffic? I have an internet facing reverse proxy front end with a static ip already, and don't want to disturb the setup for incoming traffic.

Comment: @Raj based on my knowledge, we can's use a load balancer only for outgoing traffic and without incoming traffic.

Comment: @Raj if your VMs behind a load balancer, and the VM deploy with a public IP address, we can use the public IP to connect the VM, also we can use load balancer to connect the VM.

Comment: please let me know if you would like further assistance.

Comment: Thanks a lot Jason. Sounds good to me. Will try using load balancer.

Comment: how can we set outbound ip without load balancer or public ip in my single VM ?

Comment: @Raghavendra In Azure, only azure public ip can associate to VM, we can't use the IP out of Azure.

Comment: my VM makes a call to external service and that service allow only single ip(i can set) but on VM ip keeps on changing when we check at whatsmyip.com 
so public ip is the only way to keep outbound ip fixed?

Comment: @Raghavendra your VM in ARM or ASM? if in ASM, we should use reserved IP address, if your VM in ARM, you should use static public IP address.

Comment: Thanks @JasonYe-MSFT we are using ARM so i can fix this by using static public ip only and blocking all incoming access as i dont need that :)